# How to access specific class?

Tags: java, function, menu

Hi for one of my assignments I had to make an ackermann simulator in Java and I was having trouble. The assignment was to create three variations of the ackermann project, one regular, one recursive and one through a table lookup. well, I've done all that but the part that I'm struggling with is the creating a menu for it part. I'm not sure how  to access each class when I select an option from the menu. do I need a main class for every single class or one for all of them? Here is my code and I guess my biggest question is how do I get user input when I select a version of the ackermann from the menu, thank you very much.

Here is my menu:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AckMenu
{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int choiceNumber = 0;

        introduction();
        while (choiceNumber != 4)
        {
            printMenuChoices();
            choiceNumber = readChoiceNumber();
            switch (choiceNumber)
            {
            case 1:
                //
                AckermannValue.Ack(3,3);
                break;
            case 2:
                AckermannTrace.Ack(1,3);
                break;
            case 3:
                AckermannTableLookup.getValue();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("The game is over.");
                choiceNumber = 4;
                break;
            }//switch

        }//while
    }
    private static void introduction()
    {
        System.out.println("\n\n" +
                "                   This program allows you to call the Ackermann function.");
        System.out.println("\n\n" + "Please choose one of the versions of the Ackermann function.");

    }
    private static void printMenuChoices()
    {
        System.out.println(""+
                "1) Ackermann Value.\n"+
                "2) Ackermann Trace.\n"+
                "3) Ackermann Table Lookup.\n"+
                "4) Quit.");                 
    }
    private static int readChoiceNumber()
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choiceNumber;
        String indent = "                   ";
        System.out.println("please enter the number of the method you want to call");
        choiceNumber = scan.nextInt();
        while(choiceNumber < 1 || choiceNumber > 4)
        {
            System.out.println(indent + "the number must be 1 through 4");
            System.out.println(indent + "    please enter a proper choice.  ");
            choiceNumber = scan.nextInt();
        }
        return choiceNumber;
    }
}
```

and my 3 methods, first the regular version with no recursion.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AckermannValue {

    //public static void AckMethod() throws InterruptedException {
            //static int count = 0;

            public static int Ack(int m, int n) {

                if (m < 0 || n < 0) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Non-negative args only!");
                }

                if (m == 0) 
                {
                    //count++;

                    //System.out.println("count: " + count + " M: " + m + " N: " + n);

                    return n + 1;

                }

                else if (n == 0) 
                {
                    //count++;
                //  System.out.println("count: " + count + " M: " + m + " N: " + n);

                    return Ack(m-1, 1);
                }

                else {


                    //count++;
                    //System.out.println("count: " + count + " M: " + m + " N: " + n);

                    return Ack(m-1, Ack(m,n-1));
                }
            }
            //public static void main (String args [] ) {
                //System.out.println(Ack(3,7));
            //}
        }

//}
```

Recursive method

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AckermannTrace {
    static int count = 0;

    public static int Ack(int m, int n) {

        if (m < 0 || n < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Non-negative args only!");
        }

        if (m == 0) 
        {
            count++;

            System.out.println("count: " + count + " M: " + m + " N: " + n);

            return n + 1;

        }

        else if (n == 0) 
        {
            count++;
            System.out.println("count: " + count + " M: " + m + " N: " + n);

            return Ack(m-1, 1);
        }

        else {


            count++;
            System.out.println("count: " + count + " M: " + m + " N: " + n);

            return Ack(m-1, Ack(m,n-1));
        }
    }
    //public static void main (String args [] ) {
        //System.out.println(Ack(3,7));
    //}
}
```

The table lookup version of the ackermann

```
 import java.util.Hashtable;
    public class AckermannTableLookup {

            /**
             * The table containing the values of <i>Ackermann</i>'s function.
             */

            private Hashtable<Integer, Hashtable<Integer, Integer>> table;


            /**
             * Constructs a new table, computing all values of <i>Ackermann</i>'s
             * function <i>A(i, j)</i> that are <i>n</i> or less.
             * 
             * @param n
             *              the maximum value of the new table
             */
            public void AckermannTable(int n) {
                // construct new table
                table = new Hashtable<Integer, Hashtable<Integer, Integer>>();

                // set first value
                int i = 1;
                int j = 2;
                setValue(1, 1, 2);

                while (true) {
                    int newValue = -1;

                    // compute next entry
                    if (i == 1) {
                        newValue = getValue(i, j - 1) * 2;
                    } else {
                        newValue = getValue(i - 1, getValue(i, j - 1));
                    }

                    if (newValue > n || newValue == -1) {
                        if (j == 1) {
                            // no single entry in this row - return
                            return;
                        } else {
                            // go to the next row
                            i++;
                            j = 1;
                        }
                    } else {
                        // save the computed value
                        setValue(i, j, newValue);
                        j++;
                    }
                }
            }

            /**
             * Returns the value of <i>Ackermann</i>'s function <i>A(i, j)</i>, if it
             * is <i>n</i> or less, and <code>-1</code> otherwise.
             * 
             * @param i
             *              the first parameter for <i>Ackermann</i>'s function
             * @param j
             *              the second parameter for <i>Ackermann</i>'s function
             * @return
             *              <i>A(i, j)</i>
             */
            public int getValue(int i, int j) {
                if (j == 0) {
                    return 2;
                } else {
                    if (table.containsKey(i)) {
                        Hashtable<Integer, Integer> rowI = table.get(i);

                        if (rowI.containsKey(j)) {
                            return rowI.get(j);
                        } else {
                            return -1;
                        }
                    } else {
                        return -1;
                    }
                }
            }

            /**
             * Returns the inverse value of <i>Ackermann</i>'s function <i>A(m, n)</i>.
             * 
             * @param m
             *              the first parameter for the inverse <i>Ackermann</i>'s function
             * @param n
             *              the second parameter for the inverse <i>Ackermann</i>'s function
             * @return
             *              the inverse of <i>A(m, n)</i>
             */
            public int getInverse(int m, int n) {
                if (n >= 4) {
                    int j = 0;

                    while (2 * getValue(m, j) <= n && getValue(m, j) != -1) {
                        j++;
                    }

                    return j - 1;
                } else if (m >= n) {
                    int i = 1;

                    while (getValue(i, (int)Math.floor(m / n)) != -1) {
                        i++;
                    }

                    return i;
                }

                return -1;
            }


            /**
             * Adds the passed value of <i>Ackermann</i>'s function <i>A(i, j)</i> to
             * this table.
             * 
             * @param i
             *              the first parameter for <i>Ackermann</i>'s function
             * @param j
             *              the second parameter for <i>Ackermann</i>'s function
             * @param value
             *              <i>A(i, j)</i>
             */
            private void setValue(int i, int j, int value) {
                if (!table.containsKey(i)) {
                    table.put(i, new Hashtable<Integer, Integer>());
                }

                Hashtable<Integer, Integer> rowI = table.get(i);
                rowI.put(j, value);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your classes are in the same package.
Then either make all your methods static to call them by their class names(in your lookup table class) OR
You just need to modify your switch statement.
Don't call the Ack by its classname. First create an object of its class and then call that function. For example in case1 :

```
AckermannValue object1 = new AckermannValue();
object1.Ack(3,3);
```

Now your program will run fine.